# Are GNOME keyboard shortcuts saved to a viewable file in Fedora 34?

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't find a file anywhere that seems to have the change I made to various shortcuts.

Environment information:

```
cat /usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml;echo;cat /etc/redhat-release 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gnome-version>
 <platform>40</platform>
 <minor>4</minor>
 <micro>0</micro>
 <distributor>GNOME.Org</distributor>
 <date>2021-08-19</date>
</gnome-version>
Fedora release 34 (Thirty Four)
```

With `gsettings list-schemas | grep keybindings` I am returning:

```
gsettings list-schemas | grep keybindings
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
org.gnome.mutter.wayland.keybindings
org.gnome.shell.keybindings
org.gnome.mutter.keybindings
```

None of which seem to have my saved (and functioning) binding for Obsidian anywhere. What file is GNOME actually saving my keyboard shortcuts to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is `~/.config/dconf/user`.

You can find this by monitoring changes in your home directory while you make the change (e.g. `inotifywait -r -e close_write -m ~/.config` — I wouldn't advise the home directory because inotify has to monitor each subdirectory separately). Or you can look for recently modified files after making the change, e.g. for 5 minutes:

```
find ~/.config -type f -mmin 5
```

The file is in a binary format. If you need a text form, you can get it with `gsettings list-recursively`, but I don't know how to import that back. You can also get a text form with `dconf dump /`, and that can be imported back with `dconf load /`.